# Short and well-known term for "jump from one branch to another"

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

In this sentence:

> Bird jumps from one branch to another in a strange wood.

I am interested in the part: "jumps from one branch to another". Could you tell me some well-known term of such action? So after replacing I'll get:

> Bird <term> in a strange wood.

Comment: By the way, to me that sentence is perfectly clear, and I'm not a native speaker :D I mean, it sounds common and well-known to me... The most difficult term would be "branch" but that is pretty known, I guess...

Comment: Indeed a google search for "jumps from branch to branch" finds loads of birds, squirrels and even bears https://xenophilius.wordpress.com/.../bear-pees-on-man-from-up-in-tree- jumps-from-branch-to-branch-with-bear-friends/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The bird [flitted](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flit) about in a strange wood.

Answer (score 8):

Birds [**flit**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/flit) from branch to branch.

> to move lightly and swiftly; fly, dart, or skim along

Apes [**brachiate**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachiation).

> Brachiation (from "brachium", Latin for "arm") is a form of arboreal locomotion in which primates swing from tree limb to tree limb using only their arms.

"I tried to brachiate through the trees like Tarzan, but I ended up breaking my arm instead."

Comment: Yes, but birds don't do  this (successfully or otherwise).

Comment: Right you are - I was so happy to use "brachiate" that I missed the bird part.  Editing...

Comment: And now I've added the same word as Ed Guinness, which I didn't notice until I posted.  Grrr.

Answer (score 5):

I can't think of a single term meaning *“jump from branch to branch”*. The closest I can get is to offer a somewhat more specific alternative to *jump*: ***hop***.

> **hop**
>   (of a bird or other animal) move by jumping with two or all feet at once: *a blackbird was hopping around in the sun*

If the bird is not jumping on feet, but instead flying around, I would go with ***flutter***:

> **flutter**
>   (of a bird or other winged creature) fly unsteadily or hover by flapping the wings quickly and lightly

<sup>(*New Oxford American Dictionary*)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

How about *flits*,  *flutters* or *darts*?  The first is more aimless.

Answer (score -2):

> Bird [gambols](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/gamboling) in a strange wood.

From The Free Dictionary:

> **gam·bol**
>
> *intr.v.* gam·boled or gam·bolled, gam·bol·ing or gam·bol·ling, gam·bols
>
> To leap about playfully; frolic.
>
> A playful skipping or frolicking about.

Or,

> Bird [capers](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/caper) in a strange wood.

From The Free Dictionary:

> **ca·per**
>
> 1. A playful leap or hop.
> 2. A frivolous escapade or prank.
>
> *intr.v.* ca·pered, ca·per·ing, ca·pers
>
> To leap or frisk about; frolic.

Comment: For some reason I have gambol associated with four legged creatures, and caper associated with humans... not sure why, but I have quite a strong association so it must come from childhood books, I guess.

Comment: I'd agree with Rory: they're not wrong when applied to birds, but have odd connotations.

Comment: All apologies, though I can't be held responsible for your psychological associations.

Answer (score -3):

*Brachiate* should serve the purpose best. It can do away with the use of *branch* without loss of specific meaning. It can convey an act of movement and give an imagery of the kind of movement. With any of the other words, we may still have to use *branch*: flit from branch to branch, not merely flit.

If *brachiate* brings back images of monkeys and not birds, it is only because of prior use, which should not be a constraint, I feel.

Comment: Brachiate involves swinging. It does not involve jumping.